# Check for variable in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and coming from a PHP background. When I was dealing with pages to enter content and later be able to edit it (and the pages rely on some JS files), I would just set a variable from the controller and let my view (view in the PHP MVC sense) handle it based on the variable being set. That way I could use the same javascript file for both the create and edit pages, rather than two separate JS files with only minor differences. For example

```
/some_view_file.html

<?php
    if(isset($editing) && $editing == true){
        ?>
        <script>var editing = true; </script>
        <?php
    }
    else{
        ?>
        <script>var editing = false; </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Since Django seems to be focused on templating rather than being able to intermittently write Python/HTML like you can with PHP/HTML, is there any way to accomplish what I've shown above?

I suppose a better question is how do Django programmers typically handle situations like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used PHP, but if I understand what you're trying to achieve, you want the [if/else template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

```
{% if editing %}
    <script>var editing = true; </script>
{% else %}
    <script>var editing = false; </script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django can do what PHP can do, but better, more concisely and more readably :)

```
{%  if editing  %}
    <script>var editing = true; </script>
{% else %}
      <script>var editing = false; </script>
{% endif %}
```

Where editing is passed to your template as

```
render(request, 'some_view_file.html',{'editing': true_or_false })
```

or it can come from a context processor.